# craft.entries and :first-letter

Tags: entries, css

I want to display the first character in a paragraph with a drop cap. It works fine with normal text or setting it with js, but when I use an entry field it doesn't pull out the first character. The code looks like this:

```
// css
p.dropcap { 
float: left; 
font-size: 4em;
… 
}

// html
<p class='dropcap'>{{ entry.body }}</p>
```

The first letter isn't dropped, but if I change the html to:

```
<p class='drop cap'>This is {{ entry.body }}</p>
```

The T is dropped as expected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What kind of field is `body`? If it's a rich text field, then your first character is likely a `<`, not a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Rich Text fields always return the paragraphs wrapped in `<p>` tags. So you would have to use an additional `<div>` element and apply the dropcap styles to the first `<p>` tag within that `<div>` using the [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type) pseudo-class.

```
<div class='dropcap'>
    {{ entry.body }}
</div>
```

```
.dropcap p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  float: left;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lindsey D, using a Rich Text field results in issues with :first-letter. Use a plaintext field instead.